# What kind of data structures are needed to efficiently do back-propagation in a feedforward neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, feedforward-neural-networks

In a feed-forward neural network, in order to efficiently do backpropagation, what kind of data structure is needed?

I know the weights can just be stored in an array, and you need pointers of some kind to represent connections from one layer to the next (or just a default scheme/pattern), but is anything else needed for backpropagation to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You'll need to store a little bit more to perform backward passes. You'll need to store data from the forward pass. This stored information is used for calculating the gradient.

**Overview** (warning: not trivial)

> I know the weights can just be stored in an array

You'll need a little more:

To update the weights you need to keep a "cache" of the forward pass intermediate terms. That is, forward propagation can be seen as a series of transformations on your input $X$:
$$X\xrightarrow{\Theta^{[1]}+b^{[1]}} [ Z^{[1]} \xrightarrow{\alpha^{[1]}} A^{[1]}] \xrightarrow{\Theta^{[2]}+b^{[2]}}
\dots 
\xrightarrow{\Theta^{[L]}+b^{[L]}} [ Z^{[L]} \xrightarrow{\alpha^{[L]}} A^{[L]}]\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_m\sum\limits_{n_L} loss\{A^{[L]},y\}} J
$$

where:

$Z^{[1]}=\Theta^{[1]}X+b^{[1]}$ (ie the linear part)

$A^{[l]}=\alpha^{[l]}(Z^{[l]})$ (ie element wise activation over linear part)

You need to store the $Z^{[l]}$ & $A^{[l]}$ terms in said "cache." You could store these in an array or some other similar data structure. You need these for calculating the gradient during the backwards pass.

**Syntax**

$A^{[k]}$ - this means we are indexing by layer (eg $\alpha^{[k]}$ is the activation for k-th layer)

$m$ - is the number of examples in the batch

$n_k$ - denotes the number of neurons in the k-th layer

$L$ - the number of layers (so $n_L$ is the number of neurons in last layer)

$\Theta$ - The set of *all* weights (notice no superscript)

**Backprop**

In the case of neural networks the cost is a scalar function of inputs and parameters. To get backprop started calculate the [scalar by matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix) derivative of the cost with respect to the activations of the last layer call this matrix $dA^{[L]}$. Observe:

$dA^{[L]} = \frac{\partial J(\Theta,X)}{\partial A^{[L]}}$

Next, we calculate scalar-by-matrix derivative of $Z^{[L]}$. Doing this one realizes:

$dZ^{[L]} = \frac{\partial J(\Theta,X)}{\partial Z^{[L]}} = dA\odot\alpha'^{[L]}(Z^{[L]})$

Where $\odot$ denotes element wise ([Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))) product.

With the above one can make use of the matrix definitions for back propagation:

$\text{(A)}\quad d\Theta^{[l]} = \frac{1}{m}dZ^{[l]}\times (A^{[l-1]})^T$

$\text{(B)}\quad db^{[l]} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{c=1}^m dZ^{[l](c)}$ (where the new superscript in $dZ^{[l](c)}$ denotes summing along the *batch* dimension )

$\text{(C)} \quad dZ^{[l]}= dA^{[l]}\odot \alpha^{'[l]}(Z^{[l]})$

$\text{(D)}\quad dA^{[k]} = (\Theta^{[k+1]})^T\times dZ^{[k+1]}$

And of course the wight updates are:

$\Theta^{[L]} \leftarrow \Theta^{[L]} - \frac{\eta}{m}d\Theta $

$b^{[L]} \leftarrow b^{[L]} - \frac{\eta}{m}db $

(where $\eta$ is the learning rate)

Observe, how the forward pass terms are used during the backprop calculations.

**A recommendation**

Take the A. Ng deep learning specialization. He does a good job explaining the intuition and even has a project to implement this. Though, he does not derive the back propagation equations. You can find a not so easy derivation [here](https://rojasinate.com/documents/backprop.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the explaination :).

Comment: During the backward pass can we "free" some cache? I mean when we calculate the gradient of loss $L$ with respect to layer $\ell_n$, i.e. $\frac{dL}{d\ell_{n}}$, we only need $\frac{dL}{d_{\ell-1}} \cdot \frac{d\ell_{n-1}}{d\ell_{n}}$. So can we remove from cache all terms above $\ell_{n-1}$?

Comment: @adosar You could: (1) free it as you do the backward pass (2) free it all at the end of the backward pass (3) Use a mutable data-structure and replace the data during the next pass. Depends on you preferences/needs/constraints.

Answer (score 0):

When I check [the Tensorflow tool code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), it looks like they implemented own data structure for neural network operation including back propagation. The custom data structure is [EagerTensor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.9.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L1049).

I think to speed up the operation speed, the Tensorflow used [the TFRECORD file](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) type/format.

Additionally, for neural network structure (they called Graph), they used [the Protocol Buffer format](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.10/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/tool_developers/index.md).